# How to iterate request calls and store results in on object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

The following code retrieves data on releases using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). Unfortunately, this only returns 30 (by default) or up to 100 items.

```
request(`https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/releases?page=1&per_page=30`, options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return console.log(`Error: response code ${response.statusCode}`)
    }

    let data = JSON.parse(body);

    data.forEach(function(element) {
        // do things with data
    });
});
```

Using the `page` parameter, it should be possible to retrieve items beyond the maximum per page. The question is: How can I iterate these `request` calls and return one object containing all the results?

Here's what I have tried:

```
function getReleases(callback, page = 1) {
    request(`https://api.github.com/repos/${program.owner}/${program.repo}/releases?page=${page}&per_page=30`, options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode !== 200 || error) {
            console.log(`Error ${response.statusCode}`);
            callback(null) // not sure about this
        }

        let data = JSON.parse(body);
        callback(data);
    });
}

function formatReleaseData(data) {
    // do things with data
}

formatReleaseData(show_page_count);
```

Comment: Is there a callback example that I can look at?

Comment: @Raymond Please have a look at  my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using ES6 generators to simulate synchronous requests and better control your flow.
You can read this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/write-modern-asynchronous-javascript-using-promises-generators-and-coroutines-5fa9fe62cf74#.l3s34x4hg) for deeper concepts.

I'm using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to promisify and manage the generator.

Check the code out below.

```
const request = require('request');
const Promise = require('bluebird');


function promisifyRequest(currentPage) {
  const url = `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/releases?page=${currentPage}&per_page=30`;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, options, (err, res, content) => {
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        return reject(res.statusCode);
      }
      resolve(JSON.parse(content));
    });
  });
}

function * doRequest() {
  const result = [];
  let currentPage = 1;
  //Might run until gets a empty array.
  while (true) {
    let data = yield promisifyRequest(currentPage);
    if (!data.length) break;
    //Appends the results of the current page to the total result.
    result.splice(result.length, 0, ...data);
    currentPage = currentPage + 1;
  }

  return result;
}


Promise.coroutine(doRequest)()
  .then(result => {
    //Do something with the result
  })
  .catch(errCode => console.log(`Error: response code ${errCode}`));
```